# Size of the last non-empty $k$-core of a random graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

Given $n$ and $p$ for $G(n,p)$, how to find the distribution of the size of the non-empty $k$-core with largest $k$?

In particular, what is the probability (for any $n$ and $p$) that only $c$ vertices are not in the last non-empty $k$-core, where $c$ is a constant?